# What does Similarity Score mean in gensim?

Tags: python, text, gensim, sentence-similarity

I have used **Gensim** library to find the similarity between a sentence against a collection of paragraphs, a dataset of texts. I have used Cosine similarity, Soft cosine similarity and Mover measures separately. Gensim returns a list of items including ***docid*** and ***similarity score***. For Cosine similarity and Soft cosine similarity, I guess the similarity score is the cosine between the vectors. Am I right?

In Gensim documents, they wrote it is the semantic relatedness, and no extra explanation. I have search a lot, but did not find any answer. Any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually by 'similarity', people are seeking to find a measure *semantic relatedness* - but whether the particular values calculated achieve that will depend on lots of other factors, such as the sufficiency of training data & choice of other appropriate parameters.

Within each code context, 'similarity' has no more and no less meaning than how it's calculated right there - usually, that's 'cosine similarity between vector representations'. (When there's no other hints it means something different, 'cosine similarity' is typically a safe starting assumption.)

But really: the meaning of 'similarity' at each use is no more and no less than whatever that one code path's docs/source-code dictate.

(I realize that may seem an indirect & unsatisfying answer. If there are specific uses in context in Gensim source/docs/example where the meaning is unclear, you could point those out & I might be able to clarify those more.)

Comment: Thanks gojomo, You explained well. Just please look at this link  https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/core/run_similarity_queries.html and search "semantic relatedness". No explanation here.

Comment: My sense of the use of 'semantic relatedness' in its one use on that page is that it intends to emphasize "just what the words indicate", with no other potential inputs. I didn't write that, but I think its phrasing, – "…on apparent semantic relatedness of their texts (words)" – could be roughly read as: "…on indications-of-meaning that are solely deduced from the runs-of-words".

Comment: Just as a conclusion, can we say Semantic Similarity depends on the measure we are using? For instance, when using Cosine similarity, semantic similarity means the cosine between vectors, or when we use Mover measure, similarity score means the value of Mover?

Comment: I think there's enough 'slack' in these concepts that an author should try to define them well, in context, for their purposes. (Without more context, I'd not want to make any rigorous pronouncements.)